# TCP connection between PCs in home wi-fi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, tcp

I want to establish a connection between 2 PCs. Point is to practice in writing client-server applications and similar stuff. I've heard around, that I can access another PC in network by address like "Router IP:port number". Am I right or i got it wrong?

So how do I configure router to let connections to certain ports? And what would address look like, if I'm, say, connecting to 80 port on my home server?

P.S. Will be grateful for links to some tutorials on this matter, if any.

Comment: Your router only worries about traffing coming in, and going out, to your Internet connection. It does not affect your internal traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit you have read about `router-ip:port` only applies if you want to connect to a server behind the router from the outside world.

If you want to connect to a server (say a web server like apache) on the local network it's usually as easy as starting the webserver on server one. And then on another computer enter `http://ip.of.server.one` in a webbrowser.